# How to put local html file in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json, vega-lite

I am trying to **use Vega-Lite to draw a map**. However, as a student just start self-learning it. There are a few things I am confused.

1. I do not know the **relationship between JavaScript and Vega-Lite**? We can use Vega-Lite to draw map.  So, what role do JavaScript play in order to draw a map?
   (i.e. What's the difference between writing codes in 'JavaScript' format and 'Vega-Lite' format? Is 'Vega-Lite' a new programming language? ) (i.e. I tried to search how to write JavaScript coding and turns out it looks quite different to that temple given for Vega-Lite)
2. I do not know **how to combine the Vega-Lite codes to HTML codes (in order to put in a webpage)**.
   I tried to see the temple on Vega-Lite web (https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/tutorials/getting_started.html). But, I do not understand in which part of the existing codes should I change and combine if I want to publish another vega-Lite instead of the given example (as they do not have much comments and I just start learning it.

The following code I write here does not give me any ‘Map’ on Webpage, I do not know where turns wrong?

```
# Codes I tried to combine with HTML (This is just a purely Vega-Lite code on its website)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Vega-Lite Bar Chart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.16.1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.16.8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.12.2"></script>

    <style media="screen">
      /* Add space between Vega-Embed links  */
      .vega-actions a {
        margin-right: 5px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Template for Embedding Vega-Lite Visualization</h1>
    <!-- Container for the visualization -->
    <div id="vis"></div>

    <script>
      // Assign the specification to a local variable vlSpec.
      var vlSpec = {
        "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 300,
        "data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
        "projection": {"type": "albersUsa"},
        "mark": "point",
        "encoding": {
          "longitude": {"field": "longitude", "type": "quantitative"},
          "latitude": {"field": "latitude", "type": "quantitative"},
          "size": {"value": 10}
        },
        "config": {"view": {"stroke": "transparent"}}
      };

      // Embed the visualization in the container with id `vis`
      vegaEmbed('#vis', vlSpec);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. **What is the relationship between GeoJSON, TopoJSON, and excel file?**  Vega-Lite supports TopoJSON. And we also say that we can use 'excel/csv file' for data domain. Then why we also need to transform GeoJSON to TopoJSON and put in HTML? What is the role do they play here？ Can I avoid this step if my dataset already contains "longitude" and "latitudes" in order to draw a map?
   (i.e. Is GeoJSON, TopoJSON just another type of dataset similar to excel?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your questions in order:

> 1. I do not know the relationship between JavaScript and Vega-Lite?

Vega-Lite is two things: a grammar for specifying charts via JSON, and a set of javascript libraries to ingest this JSON and render a chart.

> 2. I do not know how to combine the Vega-Lite codes to HTML codes (in order to put in a webpage).

Putting a Vega-Lite chart on a webpage requires passing the vega-lite chart specification (what you call the Vega-Lite codes) to the [vega-embed](https://github.com/vega/vega-embed) javascript library (which happens via javascript, often within an HTML page). Your example is correct, except that it refers to local data that probably doesn't exist:

```javascript
"data": {"url": "data/airports.csv"},
```

Change this to the full vega-datasets URL, and the chart will render on the page:

```javascript
"data": {"url": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/airports.csv"}
```

> 3. What is the relationship between GeoJSON, TopoJSON, and excel file?

These are all different formats for representing data. Vega-Lite supports TopoJSON for specifying geographic boundaries; if you have geographic data in another format, you'll have to convert it to TopoJSON in order to use it with Vega-Lite.

Note that TopoJSON is only required for map boundaries. If you have a CSV or JSON dataset containing columns of latitudes and longitudes, you can display them on a map background without having to convert to another format; an example is here: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/geo_layer

Comment: Thank you so much for your helping and detailed explanations. Just one more question. Do you mean CSV dataset (with latitudes & longitudes columns) just show the specific position for each point. But we cannot see directly how (e.g.) New York, Tokyo look like . But in order to have such cities' boundaries, we need to use 'TopoJSON'?

Comment: Sounds like adding a "map background" be easier than using a "TopoJSON" format data. I originally plan using https://www.naturalearthdata.com/ to find geography but I do not know how to combine such website data with my domain csv data. How can I use "map background" directly instead? Thanks again!!!

Comment: Drawing any geographic shapes in Vega-Lite requires specifying those boundaries via TopoJSON, whether those shapes are city boundaries, country boundaries, or continent boundaries. If you find boundaries specified in other formats, you will have to convert them to TopoJSON for use in Vega-Lite. For an example of displaying geographic boundaries, see the geoshape layer in https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/geo_layer

Comment: That's very kind of you. I just open the link and try to understand the coding. 1) **What is "$schema" means here? What do this link (https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json) means/represents? Should I always keep this link the same?** (Or do I need to make any changes if I want to draw other plots rather than maps)?

Comment: You can read about the meaning of terms in the specification here: https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/spec.html#top-level